# Is the semi-elasticity of a concave function always smaller than the semi-elasticity of a convex function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, economics

Consider two function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ defined on [0,1] and $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = g(1) = 1$. $f(x)$ is concave and weakly increasing, while $g(x)$ is convex and weakly increasing. Define the semi-elasticity of a function $h(x)$ as $\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}$. Can you prove that the semi-elasticity of $g$ is greater than the semi-elasticity of $f$ for all $x \in (0,1)$?

It feels like this should be true. Working through a simple case where $f(x) = x^a$ and $g(x) = x^b$ for $0 < a < 1 < b$ we get $\frac{b}{x} > \frac{a}{x}$ for the semi-elasticities. But I'm not sure for the more general case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Let $x\in (0, 1)$ and let $\phi(t)$ be the linear function such that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(x)=f(x)$. The graph of $f$ will lie above the graph of $\phi$ on $(0, x)$, since $f$ is concave, but then a drawing shows that necessarily  $f'(x)\leq \phi'(x)={f(x)\over x}$. In other words, ${f'(x)\over f(x)}\leq {1\over x}$.

Similarly, we get $g'(x)\geq {g(x)\over x}$, and hence ${g'(x)\over g(x)}\geq {1\over x}$, by comparing the graph of the convex function $g$ with the straight line through $(0, 0)$ and $(x, g(x))$.

Note that the assumption $f(1)=g(1)=1$ was not needed. This can also be seen by noting that ${h'(x)\over h(x)}$ is unchanged under vertical scaling, as $h(x)$ and $h'(x)$ will be multiplied by the same constant.

Comment: I don't think it's true that $f'(x) \leq \phi ' (x)$ for any x. Suppose $f(x) = \sqrt(x)$ and the interval $(0,1)$. Then isn't $f'(x) > \phi ' (x)$ for $x \in (0,.25)$?

Comment: @dkro23 Note that $x$ is chosen first and held fixed in the argument, and that $\phi(t) = {f(x)\over x}t$ has $x$ as a parameter. Hence different $x$ will give different functions $\phi$. It is only at the point where the two graphs intersect that you compare the derivatives.